# My off camera flash doesn’t turn on?

Tags: flash

My flash doesn’t turn on, tried to change battery but no luck. I used it only 3 times for less then 10 minutes. Any ideas what I can do? Flash: Yongnuo YN685.

Comment: Might sound silly but did you check if you put in the batteries in the right orientation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After trial & error I realised that if I close the battery cover half way it seems to turn on now but goes off if I try and close Battery cover. Maybe it’s the battery cover.